# How to display database content as an html table?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display all the data in my database in table format. I am using a while loop here. The first row looks good, but the subsequent rows don't display like a table.

```
<?php
    require_once"../connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE LOWER(trackingNo)=LOWER('$track') ORDER BY dates DESC";
    $result = $con -> query($sql);

    if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        echo "<table class='striped ex2 centered'>[The way my output looks right now][1]
            < tr > <th class='trcol' > DATE < /th> <th class='trcol'>TIME</th > <th 
            class='trcol' > LOCATION < /th> <th class='trcol'>STATUS</th > <th 
            class='trcol' > REMARKS < /th></tr >";

        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $dates = $row['dates']; enter code here
            $tim = $row['tim'];
            $status = $row['status'];
            $remarks = $row['remarks'];
            $location = $row['location'];

            echo" <tr><td>".$dates."</td> <td>".$tim."</td> 
                < td > ".$location." < /td> <td>".$status."</td >
                <td>".$remarks." < /td></tr > </table>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $con -> close();
?>
```

This is how it currently looks like

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your closing table tag is inside the while-loop, so no iterations after the first will actually be part of the table. Edit your code to look like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dates = $row['dates'];
    $tim = $row['tim'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $remarks = $row['remarks'];
    $location = $row['location'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$dates."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$tim."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$location."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$status."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$remarks."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to **take your `</table>` outside** of the *while* loop.
So, it would be -

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $dates = $row['dates'];
    $tim = $row['tim'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $remarks = $row['remarks'];
    $location = $row['location'];

    echo" <tr>
            <td>".$dates."</td> <td>".$tim."</td> 
            <td> ".$location." </td> <td>".$status."</td >
            <td>".$remarks." </td>
        </tr>";         // <-- removed table closing
}

echo "</table>";        // <-- close table here
```